# How to auto insert only new record from MS Access to MySql using ODBC driver?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, odbc

I am working on retrieving Attendance Logs from MS Access to MySql Database.
I want to get/retrieve only new records from MS Access Datasource and Upload to MySql Database (Automatically is preferred).
Below is my current code, please help:

```
<?php 
// Connect to MySql Local Database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

// Connect to Microsoft Access Using ODBC Driver
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\Program Files (x86)\ZKTeco\att2000.mdb", "", "");

// Check if Connect works
if($connection){
    echo odbc_autocommit($connection);
    $QUERY  = odbc_exec($connection, "SELECT * FROM `CHECKINOUT`") or die(odbc_error($connection));


 //If have records in MS Access Data Source
        if(odbc_fetch_row($QUERY) > 0){
            while ($ATT = odbc_fetch_array($QUERY)) {
                $result = $ATT["CHECKTIME"];

            // Here I want to Insert only New Records from MS Access 

            $INSERT = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `odbc`.`attendance` (`DATETIME`, `DATE`, `TIME`) VALUES ('$result', '$result', '$result')") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        }
    }
    echo odbc_commit($connection);
}else{
    echo "False";
}
?>
```

Comment: First you should explain what's not working with your code. Then IF this is a Oneshot operation it would be a lot more easier to do this from MS Access instead of PHP.

Comment: What defines new records? Do you really mean non-duplicate records?

Comment: @Parfait yes, I don't want the duplicated records, because it duplicates record every time when I submit this form.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a temp table, `attendance_temp` that is structurally the exact same as final table, `attendance` but is regularly cleaned out with each run of script:

```
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM `odbc`.`attendance_temp`");    # OUTSIDE WHILE LOOP
...
$INSERT = mysqli_query($con, 
                       "INSERT INTO `odbc`.`attendance_temp` (`DATETIME`, `DATE`, `TIME`)
                        VALUES ('$result', '$result', '$result')")
```

Once temp table is populated, then run a [NOT IN / NOT EXISTS / LEFT JOIN...IS NULL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) query from temp to final table to avoid duplicate records in final, destination table:

```sql
INSERT INTO odbc.`attendance` (`DATETIME`, `DATE`, `TIME`)
SELECT t.`DATETIME`, t.`DATE`, t.`TIME`
FROM `odbc`.`attendance_temp` t
LEFT JOIN `odbc`.`attendance` f
ON t.`DATETIME` = f.`DATETIME`
WHERE f.`DATETIME` IS NULL;
```